# How to convert Image to ImageSource Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Hey I have image generated in ZXingBarcodeImageView I want to convert that to ImageSource so I can bind the Image in xaml, How to achieve this, Good Day and Thank you

```
 public class GenerateCode: IGenerateCode
 {
    ZXingBarcodeImageView barcode;

    public ImageSource GenerateQr(string code)
    {
        barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 100;
        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 100;
        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
        barcode.BarcodeValue = code;
        return barcode; error as barcode is an image
    }
 }



<Image Source={Binding imgSource} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you are using a platform specific component to generate images. This component either stores the generated image into the filesystem or returns a binary representation in memory.

To convert a file into an `ImageSource`, you would use `ImageSource.FromFile()`. To convert a stream, use `ImageSource.FromStream()`.

You can find the APIs [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource/) and some great documentation [there](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/).

In your case above, the `BindingContext` (whether that's a page or a ViewModel does not matter) will have to expose a public property of type `ImageSource` and returns the converted image using either of the methods above.

Answer (score 0):

The class `ZXingBarcodeImageView` doesn't expose an `ImageSource` property because it's meant to be used **instead of** `Image`. You can place it either in XAML or C#.

For example:

XAML:

```
<!-- this goes in your root node -->
<!-- xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" -->

<zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView BarcodeValue="{Binding Code}" BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE" BarcodeOptions="{Binding Options}" />
```

C# backend:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    BindingContext = new
    {
        Code = code;
        Options = new EncodingOptions()
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
            Margin = 10,
        }
    };
}
```